# Visual Studio 2010 WPF Project with Microsoft Ribbon Control Oct 2010 : EDIT Design Time in GUI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, ribbon, ribbon-control

I always end up editing the xaml Code. Isnt there a drag and drop design time editing in the WPF Form Designer?

(Add Ribbons to Ribbon Windows, Add Status Bars, RibbonButtons etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here is: no, there is not.